# Handle traces that overflow the grid on plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dash app and I have the following code which build a grid of 5 Indicators on one row

```
indicators_ptf = go.Figure()
indicators_ptf.layout.template = CHART_THEME
indicators_ptf.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = totalprolos,
    number = {'prefix': " $"},
    title = {"text": "<br><span style='font-size:0.7em;color:gray'>Profit/Loss</span>"},
    delta = {'position': "bottom", 'reference': totalprolos - portfolio_pct/100, 'relative': False, 'valueformat': ".2%"},
    domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 0}))

indicators_ptf.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = availableCash,
    number = {'prefix': "$"},
    title = {"text": "<br><span style='font-size:0.7em;color:gray'>Available Cash</span>"},
    delta = {'position': "bottom", 'reference': 10000, 'relative': False},
    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 0}))

indicators_ptf.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = grandTotal,
    number = {'prefix': "$"},
    title = {"text": "<span style='font-size:0.7em;color:gray'>Total Value</span>"},
    delta = {'position': "bottom", 'reference': 10000, 'relative': False},
    domain = {'row': 2, 'column': 0}))

row_n=3
for stock in stocks:
    indicators_ptf.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode = "number+delta",
        value = stock['prolos'],
        number = {'prefix': "$"},
        title = {"text": stock['symbol']},
        delta = {'position': "bottom", 'reference': stock['prolos'] - stock['perc_change']/100, 'relative': False, 'valueformat': ".2%"},
        domain = {'row': row_n, 'column': 0}))
    row_n += 1


indicators_ptf.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 5, 'columns': 1, 'pattern': "independent"},
    margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=30, b=30)
)
```

The issue is in the for loop on row 3 where if I have more then 2 stocks in the portfolio, the additional stocks will overide the values on other rows:

[image]

As can be seen META stock overides the other stock. How can I make that the META stock and other down the line will be hidden below and that I could scroll down and see them?

I tried fig.update_traces(colorbar_ticklabeloverflow=....
and fig.update_yaxes(ticklabeloverflow=)
but it changed nothing.

My dash layout is:

```
dash_app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.H2('PORTFOLIO OVERVIEW', className='text-center text-primary, mb-3'))),  # header row

        dbc.Row([  # start of second row
            dbc.Col([  # first column on second row
            html.H5('Total Portfolio Value ($USD)', className='text-center'),
            dcc.Graph(id='chrt-portfolio-main',
                    figure=chart_ptfvalue,
                    style={'height':550}),
            html.Hr(),
            ], width={'size': 8, 'offset': 0, 'order': 1}),  # width first column on second row
            dbc.Col([  # second column on second row
            html.H5('Portfolio', className='text-center'),
            dcc.Graph(id='indicators-ptf',
                    figure=indicators_ptf,
                    style={'height':550, 'overflowY': 'scroll', 'maxHeight': '550px'}),
            html.Hr()
            ], width={'size': 2, 'offset': 0, 'order': 2}),  # width second column on second row
            dbc.Col([  # third column on second row
            html.H5('S&P500', className='text-center'),
            dcc.Graph(id='indicators-sp',
                    figure=indicators_sp500,
                    style={'height':550}),
            html.Hr()
            ], width={'size': 2, 'offset': 0, 'order': 3}),  # width third column on second row
        ]),  # end of second row

        dbc.Row([  # start of third row
            dbc.Col([  # first column on third row
                html.H5('Monthly Return (%)', className='text-center'),
                dcc.Graph(id='chrt-portfolio-secondary',
                    figure=fig_growth2,
                    style={'height':380}),
            ], width={'size': 8, 'offset': 0, 'order': 1}),  # width first column on second row
            dbc.Col([  # second column on third row
                html.H5('Top 15 Holdings', className='text-center'),
                dcc.Graph(id='pie-top15',
                    figure = donut_top,
                    style={'height':380}),
            ], width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0, 'order': 2}),  # width second column on second row
        ])  # end of third row

    ], fluid=True)
```

Comment: I was able to confirm the phenomenon with the `plotly indicator`. My environment is the latest version of `jupyterlab`. It seems to be affected by the lack of display area. The workaround I have done is to add a row and specify the graph size. `indicators_ptf.update_layout(autosize=True,height=600,grid={'rows': 6, 'columns': 1, 'pattern': "independent"},margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=30, b=30))`

Comment: Thanks, one issue still remain though, instead of 5 viewable indicators, there are 6.  I am trying to set it up so only 5 will be viewable and the rest will be hidden but I could scroll down to view them.

Comment: Does it show up in the "do not show" setting? In the loop process, I set each ticker to show or hide, but the line for the ticker that I set to hide is blank. I cannot reproduce the commented event.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a sulotion to this, hope it helps some one.

The line

```
indicators_ptf.update_layout(
grid = {'rows': 5, 'columns': 1, 'pattern': "independent"},
margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=30, b=30)
```

)

Needed to add a height argument that is larger then the height argument mention on the Dash dcc.Graph

So in my case the sulotion was

```
indicators_ptf.update_layout(
        height=len(all_tickers)*110 + 330,
        grid = {'rows': 8, 'columns': 1, 'pattern': "independent"},
        margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=30, b=30)
    )
```

[image]